# Llamar un evento con una combinación de teclas con Javascript

Tags: javascript

siempre la más grande comunidad, tengo una curiosidad, encontré que se puede generar eventos con una combinación de teclas con ayuda de Javascript, un ejemplo con una librería hotkeys.js con el siguiente código se abre un sitio web

```
$(document).bind('keydown', 'ctrl+a', function(){
  //alert("Has pulsado ctrl+a");
  var win = window.open("https://www.google.com", '_blank');
  win.focus();
});

$(document).bind('keydown', 'ctrl+l', function(){
  alert("Has pulsado ctrl+l");
});
```

Quiero utilizar la misma función para llamar un evento div que contiene su id, tengo una pequeña idea en lugar de esto:

```
  var win = window.open("https://www.google.com", '_blank');
  win.focus();
```

Sería algo así, pero soy novato, alguien me ayuda. Gracias.

```
$('#nombreId').toggle('');
```

Answer (score 0):

*jQuery* no va a analizar combinación de teclas, eso debes hacerlo de "forma manual", tomando en consideración las propiedades del [evento](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/).

Entonces, la solución es que se detecte cualquier tecla presionada y, dentro de la función, primero ver si está presionada la tecla CTRL y analizar las combinaciones deseadas.

```js
// Escuchar cuando se presione cualquier tecla (o combinación)
// Recibir evento como parámetro
$(document).bind('keydown', function (e) {
    // Verificar que se pulsó la tecla CTRL (en Windows) o ⌘ (en MAC)
    if (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) {
        // Analizar las combinaciones permitidas en el proyecto
        if(String.fromCharCode(e.which).toLowerCase() === 'a') {
            console.log( 'Presionaste CTRL + A' );
        } else if(String.fromCharCode(e.which).toLowerCase() === 'l') {
            console.log( 'Presionaste CTRL + L' );
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Nota:** Ten en cuenta que los navegadores usan diferentes combinaciones de teclas para determinadas tareas y podría interferir con el funcionamiento de tu proyecto y, de ser el caso, buscar otra combinación o tratar de evitar el comportamiento del navegador con [e.preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)